# HTML multi select tag how to select multiple options via click event

Tags: jquery, html

I dont want to have to ctrl+click in order to select multiple somethings from the list. all i want is to click something - it is selected. or click again - it is deselected. sounds super simple but i have been trying for a while and i cant get it to work. here is an example of my list. the list of options is generated on load so i dont know how many options ill have but if i can just get index onclick and use that to set selected=true then that will solve my problem. If anyone can help.

example of the select list.

```
  <select id="test" multiple>
      <option selected value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
  </select>
  <script>
     $("#test option").click(function () {

        //ToDo
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: Ctrl key and dragging the mouse for multiple selections don't work with this code :(

```js
var selections;
$("#test").mousedown(function(e) {
  selections = $(this).val();

}).click(function() {

  if (selections == null) {
    var selected = -1;
    selections = [];
  } else
    var selected = selections.indexOf($.isArray($(this).val()) ? $(this).val()[$(this).val().length - 1] : $(this).val());

  if (selected >= 0)
    selections.splice(selected, 1);
  else
    selections.push($(this).val()[0]);

  $('#test option').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('selected', selections.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" multiple>
  <option selected value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The code in the `each` could be just `$(this).prop('selected', selections.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0);`. But this code also depends on the values being unique on their first character. I would just use the entire value instead.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to unselect all options.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for the suggestion, I updated the code... When I try it with values which have same first characters, it works fine. Is there something I cannot see?

Comment: It's quite a mix of vanilla and jquery but it works so I gave it an upvote

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate take on the answer. This code does the following:

When I push the mouse button on an option, track:

- was it previously selected?
- what were the selected options?

Then, when I release the mouse button:

- select all of the options that were previously selected, and
- if the current option was previously selected, unselect it.

The biggest difference with the other solution is that these pieces of information are tracked using the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) mechanism provided by jQuery.

```js
$("#test option").on("mousedown", function() {
  var $me = $(this);
  $me.data("was-selected", $me.prop("selected"));
  $("#test").data("selected", $("#test").find("option:selected"));
}).on("mouseup", function() {
  var $me = $(this);
  $("#test").data("selected").prop("selected", true);
  $me.prop("selected", !$me.data("was-selected"));
});;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" multiple>
  <option selected value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```